# Bizarre behavior with LoginView on MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, pageload, loginview

A question submitted by [J. Han](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336713/asp-net-null-reference-exception-due-to-not-finding-controls/32337853#32337853) introduced a NullRef exception issue. While coming up with a solution I found some bizarre behavior with Page_Load and LoginView.

There seems be a disconnect in accessibility of controls until the page is fully loaded. This is causing the server side controls to be Null referenced unless you forcibly expose them.

### WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div ID="success" style="visibility:visible" runat="server">         
        <asp:button id="btnClick" onclick="btnClick_Click" runat="server" text="Click Me!" />
    </div>

    <div ID="fail" style="visibility:hidden" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDontClick" onclick="btnDontClick_Click" runat="server" Text="Do Not Click Me..." />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

### WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Master.FindControl("LoginView1").FindControl("MainContent");
            if (Page.FindControl("fail") != null)
            {
                fail.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
                success.Style.Add("visibility", "Visible");
            }
            else
            {
                fail.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
                success.Style.Add("visibility", "Visible");
            }
        }

        protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fail.Style.Add("visibility", "Visible");
            success.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
        }

        protected void btnDontClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fail.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
            success.Style.Add("visibility", "Visible");
        }
    }
}
```

### Site2.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site2.master.cs" Inherits="Test.Site2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="body">
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>

            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Testing

The first time you run this you should get a NullRef exception on the `fail.Style.Add("visibility","hidden");` line. We should note that if you comment out these two `Style.Add` lines, the page renders and the button works as designed.

### Now to add the confusion...

Uncomment the commented FindControl line:

```
this.Master.FindControl("LoginView1").FindControl("MainContent");;
```

Now this time you run it, it should behave as one would expect.

### The Question

Why does this line of code expose the controls? Is there a "control cache" that isn't getting refreshed upon entry of Page_Load? Running FindControl() refreshes this cache? Why aren't these controls exposed already?

Maybe this is by design, but unlikely.

Hopefully someone on here has some insight into why this happens....